# Having problem with python syntax while writing a calculator app

Tags: python

[-> The Codes Image <-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6po2Z.png)

I wrote this calculator app today and for some reason this just doesn't work.

when I use `-`, `/`, and `*` it gives a syntax error and when I use the `+` it doesn't treat the numbers as numbers but rather adds them together like a string.

btw this code worked just fine with python 3.9 but has problems like this with python 3.11

could anyone help with this please?
I have tried maybe editing or something but no luck yet

Comment: Please post a [mcve] **as text**. Not a link to a picture. My python doesn't run pictures.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also post full traceback you get. [ask].

Comment: i sent the picture so someone can diognose it

Comment: _" when I use the + it doesn't treat the numbers as numbers but rather adds them together like a string."_: That's a hint that your "numbers" aren't really numbers but strings -- why else would they be added like they're strings? _"this code worked just fine with python 3.9"_: No chance this is true. There have been no changes between python 3.9 and 3.11 that would automatically convert strings to numbers.  _" I have tried maybe editing or something"_: You don't know what you've tried?

Comment: heres the deal i dont know why my numbers are treated as string

Answer (score -1, accepted):

looking at the image you attached I see the problem, you need to change the following lines of code

From this

```py
Number_one = input(int())
Number_two = input(int())
```

To this

```py
Number_one = int(input())
Number_two = int(input())
```